# PHP pages are not parsed by Apache on CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have installed Centos 5.x, Apache 2.2, PHP 5.3 and MySQL 5.5. I also installed phpMyAdmin. I am able to access phpMyAdmin through the browser without any issues. However, when I create a simple index.php with phpinfo() function in the default directory, that page is served without php parsing.

As we all know, phpMyAdmin is a php application. This is working fine from the same server but not the simple php page from the doc root directory ??!!!. Of course, I tried moving this page into phpMyAdmin folder and tried accessing it, but no success.

Please note that I updated httpd.conf file with appropriate directives based on the php installation guide.Following directives were added to httpd.conf.

```
AddTyoe application/x-httpd-php 
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so 
<FilesMatch "\.php$"> 
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php 
</FilesMatch>
```

File locations are:

- docroot - /var/www/html
- phpMyAdmin folder - /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin

File privileges are:

```
[root@linuxdev1 html]# ls -Z 
-rwxr-xr-x root root index.php 
drwxr-xr-x root root phpMyAdmin 
-rw-r--r-- root root phpMyAdmin-3.4.3.2-english.tar.gz 
drwxr-xr-x root root test1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the "appropriate directives" of both directories.

Comment: And the permissions and SELinux properties. ls -Z

Comment: Following directives were added to httpd.conf

AddTyoe application/x-httpd-php


LoadModule php5_module  /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so


<FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

Comment: I am not sure where to look for SELinux properties

Comment: Run `ls -Z` in the directories and it will display the SELinux properties for the files and folders as well as permissions and ownership.

Comment: [root@linuxdev1 html]# ls -Z
-rwxr-xr-x  root root                                  index.php
drwxr-xr-x  root root                                  phpMyAdmin
-rw-r--r--  root root                                  phpMyAdmin-3.4.3.2-english.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x  root root                                  test1
[root@linuxdev1 html]#

Comment: @Ram Please edit your question to add additional information, comments are not appropriate for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll guess that you used short tags `<? ... ?>` in your script and that the php.ini directive [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) is disabled (0).

Change your tags to  `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: You were right on target. When I used the long tags it worked. Thanks.

Comment: +1 ... Because you deserve it!